# Boundedness of $A$ in the operator equation $Au = f$ of $-\Delta u(x)=f(x)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

We consider the boundary value problem on a bounded, open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ determining $u : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that
$$-\Delta u(x)=f(x), \qquad u|_{\partial\Omega}=0,$$
for a given function $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$. The variational formulation reads: find $u \in H^1_0 (\Omega)$ such that
$$a(u, v) := (\nabla u,\nabla v)_0 = (f, v)_0 \ \text{for all}\ v \in H^1_0 (\Omega) \quad (\ast)$$
for a given function $f \in H^{−1}(\Omega)$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)_0$ denotes the standard $L_2$-inner product on $\Omega$. Introducing the differential operator
$$A:H^1_0 (\Omega)\rightarrow H^{−1}(\Omega), \quad \langle Au,v\rangle:=a(u,v), \quad u,v\in H^1_0 (\Omega),$$
we can rewrite $(\ast)$ as an operator equation
$$Au = f$$
in the Sobolev space $H^1_0 (\Omega)$. Operator $A$ is just $A=-\Delta$. Under what conditions the operator $A$ (and so $-\Delta$) is a bounded operator? I think it depends on the topology of which we equip the spaces, but I'm not sure. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the norm is understood as the natural induced norm
\begin{equation}
\|A\|:=\sup_{\|u\|_{H^1}\leq 1}(\sup_{\|v\|_{H^1}\leq 1}|(\nabla u,\nabla v)|),
\end{equation}

then from Hölder's inequality we trivially have $\|A\|\leq 1$.

---

With definition we have
\begin{align}
\|A\|&=\sup_{\|u\|_{H^1}\leq 1}(\sup_{\|v\|_{H^1}\leq 1}|(\nabla u,\nabla v)|)\\
&=\sup_{\|u\|_{H^1}\leq 1}(\sup_{\|v\|_{H^1}\leq 1}|\int \nabla u\cdot\nabla v|)\\
&\leq\sup_{\|u\|_{H^1}\leq 1}(\sup_{\|v\|_{H^1}\leq 1}\int|\nabla u\cdot\nabla v|)\\
&\leq\sup_{\|u\|_{H^1}\leq 1}(\sup_{\|v\|_{H^1}\leq 1}(\int|\nabla u|^2\int|\nabla v|^2))\\
&\leq\sup_{\|u\|_{H^1}\leq 1}(\sup_{\|v\|_{H^1}\leq 1}\|u\|_{H^1}^2\|v\|_{H^1}^2)\\
&\leq 1.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, how can we apply  Hölder's inequality? Could you add some step, please ?

Comment: Already edited :) Hope that can help you.

Comment: PS. One last question. These assumptions also make it invertible?

Comment: I read again your notation. You said $f\in H^{-1}$. You can certainly write $(f,v)_0$, but in fact, the inner product here which related to Riesz representation theorem is $(f,v)_{H^1}=(f,v)_0+(\nabla f, \nabla v)_0$, and in particular, $f$ is in $H_0^1$. Applying the Lax-Milgram theorem (notice you have $H_0^1$ space here, the billinear form is coercive on this space), the operator is invertible, but $Au=f$ means $<Au,v>=(f,v)_{H_0^1}$.

Comment: What you meant about $f\in H^{-1}$ for $f\in L_2$ was perhaps $\int f\cdot\in H^{-1}$, then there exists $\bar{f}\in H^{1}_0$ such that $(f,v)_0=(\bar{f},v)_0+(\nabla\bar{f},\nabla v)_0$, and the $\bar{f}$ is the $f$ I meant in the last comment.

Comment: And to apply coercivity, you may need the Poincare's inequality. That needs some smooth boundary conditions, like $\Omega$ should be a Lipschitz domain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25992/discussion-between-mark-and-yongyong).